# How to remove hr tag from the last post?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to remove the last hr tag from the post

Full image of the code :

[image]

HTML code:

```
  @forelse (auth()->user()->experiences->sortByDesc('subject') as $experience)
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <main class="experience" id="post">
                        <span class="button is-danger is-small text-right is-rounded" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ExperienceDeleteModal{{ $experience->id }}"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></span>
                        <span class="button is-link is-small text-right is-rounded"   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ExperienceEditModal{{ $experience->id }}"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></span>
                        <h1>{{$experience->subject}}</h1>
                        <p class="subtitle is-6">{{$experience->experience_desc}}</p>
                        <hr>
                      </main>
                    </div>
                    @include('frontend.profile.experience.edit')
                    @include('frontend.profile.experience.delete')
                @empty
                    <p class="pl-3">لا يوجد خبرات في الوقت الحالي </p>
  @endforelse
```

I tried this code but it removes all hr tag :

```
#post hr:last-child {
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: And without "last-child"? "experience" is an ID anyway so there is only one hr inside.

Comment: if it's inside a for-each loop can you have an incrementer declared outside the loop but increase it with each iteration inside the loop. Before you print the hr tag you can have an if statement that checks the current value of the incrementer

Comment: You appear to be using some kind of framework for generating the HTML. You can generally use that framework to not output the `<hr>` at all.

Comment: Can we see the actual markup with repeated hrs?

Comment: Note, as @Effection implies, IDs must be unique to the document, and generally the `main` element should only appear once per document, so you may want to reconsider your document structure.

Comment: Update it the post with full code sorry about that!

Comment: Please upload your code *as text*, not as an image.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @Amy Done with full code!

Comment: What does `@include('frontend.profile.experience.edit')
                    @include('frontend.profile.experience.delete')` do? Can you actually show rendered code and not template markup. The markup is actually what is making it hard to write the selector.

Comment: @epascarello it just modal bootstrap  for edit and delete the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest changing the HTML structure somewhat. Here I've added a class to your containing element, the "row", then moved the "col-md-12" class to the `main` element.

```
<div class="row experiences">
    @forelse (auth()->user()->experiences->sortByDesc('subject') as $experience)
      <main class="experience col-md-12">
        <span class="button is-danger is-small text-right is-rounded" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ExperienceDeleteModal{{ $experience->id }}"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></span>
        <span class="button is-link is-small text-right is-rounded"   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ExperienceEditModal{{ $experience->id }}"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></span>
        <h1>{{$experience->subject}}</h1>
        <p class="subtitle is-6">{{$experience->experience_desc}}</p>
        <hr>
      </main>
        @include('frontend.profile.experience.edit')
        @include('frontend.profile.experience.delete')
    @empty
        <p class="pl-3">لا يوجد خبرات في الوقت الحالي </p>
    @endforelse
</div>
```

That should produce HTML something like the below code. The CSS takes advantage of the use of the `main` element and finds the last `main` under the "experiences", finds the `hr`, and hides it.

```css
.experiences main:last-of-type hr { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="row experiences">
  <main class="experience col-md-12">
    <span class="button is-danger is-small text-right is-rounded" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ExperienceDeleteModal{{ $experience->id }}"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></span>
    <span class="button is-link is-small text-right is-rounded" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ExperienceEditModal{{ $experience->id }}"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></span>
    <h1>{{$experience->subject}}</h1>
    <p class="subtitle is-6">{{$experience->experience_desc}}</p>
    <hr>
  </main>
  <main class="experience col-md-12">
    <span class="button is-danger is-small text-right is-rounded" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ExperienceDeleteModal{{ $experience->id }}"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></span>
    <span class="button is-link is-small text-right is-rounded" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ExperienceEditModal{{ $experience->id }}"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></span>
    <h1>{{$experience->subject}}</h1>
    <p class="subtitle is-6">{{$experience->experience_desc}}</p>
    <hr>
  </main>
  <main class="experience col-md-12">
    <span class="button is-danger is-small text-right is-rounded" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ExperienceDeleteModal{{ $experience->id }}"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></span>
    <span class="button is-link is-small text-right is-rounded" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ExperienceEditModal{{ $experience->id }}"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></span>
    <h1>{{$experience->subject}}</h1>
    <p class="subtitle is-6">{{$experience->experience_desc}}</p>
    <hr>
  </main>
</div>
```

Obviously, if your `@include('frontend.profile.experience.edit')` or `@include('frontend.profile.experience.delete')` insert a `main` element, this may not work...

Comment: Thank you so much, great suggest!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `<main />`  is what you are return for each iteration, you will want to have a unique `id` for each one.

```
<main class="experience" id="experience-{{$experience->id}}">
 <h1>{{$experience->subject}}</h1>
 <p class="subtitle is-6">{{$experience->experience_desc}}</p>
 <hr>
</main>
```

then in your CSS you will want to change your rule to

```
.experience:last-child hr {
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: The repeated element is the main's parent as seen by the actual code.

Comment: Yeah I know but believe me, it does not work assuming to your answer

Comment: @ahmed because this answer was based on the first snipplet you posted...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel, you can use the [$loop](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#the-loop-variable) variable:

```
@if (!$loop->last)
    <hr />
@endif
```